# Using PowerShell, identify the last TWO most recently created files in a single directory, compare them, and spit out only the differences to a file

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, compare, diff

I need some assistance on my attempt at my 3rd PowerShell script. I have a report being generated daily. It puts the information I need into a txt file in a Reports folder on my desktop. I'm needing a way to compare the most recent LAST report with the newest and then output the differences to a different file for review at a later date. This script will run as a .bat on every computer getting these reports (obviously only running if the computer is turned on so the dates will not always be back to back).

There will only be a single write to this directory every 24 hours which will be the daily generated report. The daily report file is named with the computer name in file name aa111111-report-currentdate.txt. If the 'Report' directory contains 2 or more files, run a compare on the most recently created file and the previously created file then spit out the differences to a new file in a different directory to identify new changes manually. Here is what I have:

```
if ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\x\Desktop\Report -File | Measure-Object).count -ge 2) {
    Compare-Object (Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report' | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1) -DifferenceObject (Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report' | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 2) -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[-]report[-]\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}\.txt$' -and $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report_Differences\differences.txt' -Width 9999999
}
```

`(Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report' | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1)` looks like this:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                         
-a----        5/23/2020   8:45 PM         670146 DESKTOP-aa111111-report-2020-05-23.txt
```

`(Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report' | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 2)` looks like this:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                         
-a----        5/23/2020   8:45 PM         670146 DESKTOP-aa111111-report-2020-05-23.txt                                                                                        
-a----        5/24/2020   9:45 PM         793676 DESKTOP-aa222222-report-2020-05-24.txt
```

#### Problem 1:

My current solution seems to identify both files as a single query and I'm not sure how to have PowerShell understand I need them identified separately to do a diff. How can I specify a compare on only the 2 most recently created files in the directory, diff them, then spit out results to another file in a separate directory WITHOUT knowing the exact file name (only the regex pattern which will match).

Extra: Is there a method to get the difference file to be formatted such as 'date of last file vs date of today' so I know which files/dates found the differences?

**UPDATE**

`$last2createdfiles = Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report' | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 2`

However, the below PowerShell does not output the file differences to a file. It only shows the output of the file name properties of $last2createdfiles[0] such as mode, lastwritetime,length, and name.

`if ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\x\Desktop\Report -File | Measure-Object).count -ge 2) {
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $last2createdfiles[0] -DifferenceObject $last2createdfiles[1] -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\users\x\Desktop\Report_Differences\differences.txt'
}`

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't try to do it as a one-liner; do it as a two-step. Step 1 is to get the two files that you need, and put their file objects (NOT their content) into an array: `$a = (Get-ChildItem ... )`. This array will have two 'slots', `$a[0]` and `$a[1]`. Then, step 2 is simply to run `Compare-Object` on the two, using `$a[0]` as the `-InputObject` and `$a[1]` as the `-CompareObject`, or vice-versa, as appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I do not understand how to format it correctly in order to spit out the difference between each file's contents. I'm looking for a comparison between $last2createdfiles[0] and $last2createdfiles[1]. What is currently shown does not output differences to a file but instead just writes out the name of the oldest file properties. Do you have a written example?

Comment: Sorry; I was a bit unclear and in haste when I wrote that. It should have been `(Get-Content -Path $a[0].FullName)` and `(Get-Content -Path $a[1].FullName)` for the `-InputObject` and `-CompareObject`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin This answers my question. Thank you!